# onClick not working correctly in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a button onClick show a message in Jetpack Compose, but it just doesn't work. It seems like if I wasn't pressing it.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Button(
                onClick = {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("Auth:Auth:", "Auth: true")
                    //biometricPrompt.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo)
                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color(0xFF03A278),
                    contentColor = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.White
                )
            ) {
                Log.d("Auth:Auth:", "Auth: text")
                Text(getString(R.string.authenticate_button))
            }
```

The logd message above "Text" is showing, but not the one under "Toast". The toast isn't showing either.

Also, when I click on it I get these messages on Logcat:
[Logcat messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdXXX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, there was a PopUpSpinner hanging around and messing it all up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in your class or activity pass the context as this:

```
val context = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
```

Or you can also do this:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```

Both will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the problem is that some other transparent UI element overlaps your button. It could happen in some containers like `Box()` or `Card()` when after your `Button` you have some element with `fillMaxWidth` or `fillMaxHeight`.

Also sometimes it could happen even when Button at the bottom of your compose function but you played with `elevation` param.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using toast in correct way. And I don't remember that we can pass
this@MainActivity or any other Activity in which you are it will give error.
To pass context do this:

```
val context = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
```

And in onClick do this:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```